# Error trying to call $.post() and $post

Tags: jquery, post

I'm trying to invoke $.post() function but when I press the button nothings happen, but if I try to call $post()function the result is an error but the code works. I really don't understand.

In the image, the first option gets an error but works, I mean the $_post variable is sent. the second does not do anything, not even an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nueva_categoria").submit(function(){

        var datos_categoria = $(this).serialize();      
        $post("articulo_controller.class.php", datos_categoria);
        return false;
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nueva_categoria").submit(function(){

        var datos_categoria = $(this).serialize();      
        $.post("articulo_controller.class.php", datos_categoria);
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: What's the error your getting?

Answer (score 0):

`$post` doesn't exist, unless you define it (and since you get an error, I'm guessing you haven't). `$.post` is a correct invocation of the jQuery ajax post shorthand.

The reason the data is being submitted in your first example is that the `$post` line is throwing an error. Because of that, your javascript execution is stopped. So `return false;` is never executing. Hence, the form is being submitted.

The second example should submit an ajax POST. There is probably an error that you are not seeing. Open the network inspection tools of your browser, and you should be able to see the request. Is the address correct, or should you have, for instance, a leading `/` in that url? How are you currently verifying that the data is or isn't being posted?

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the correct one, but the submit is stoped by the "return false;".

I think you need to see if your ajax is correct and not returning any error.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'articulo_controller.class.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos_categoria,
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

That way you can see if you ajax is correct.